# How to view live game server chat on website?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web

I play swat 4 v1.0 multiplayer . I have seen this website www.houseofpain.tk is showing live server chat viewer on website, please take a look at the website "server viewer". How to make my gameserver send live chat to my website? I think ajax is used by the other site. Donno what to do. I would be grateful to you if you could show me way so that I could make my clan members happy with this new feature.

regards,
vinay

Answer (score 0):

They probably have a **mod** on their server that puts the messages somewhere, and their webserver uses a script to read the messages. Why don't you ask them which mod they are using?

Or take a look at http://www.markmods.com/ and check out his webadmin module, maybe that is what you want?

Comment: No, I know about the webadmin. Yes, I asked them and they have not answered. Maybe they dont wanna share it.